# How to store user's actions on radio buttons via angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm making a quiz single page application using angularjs, ef and asp.net 5. Angularjs using couple days and there is one thing which i can't solve, I'll try to explain.

So, on main page I've quiz question and radio buttons(Yes or No), when i'm press one of them, click next for next question and back to review if the 1st question is answered, the radio button just refreshed. So the question is how to save the options on radio buttons which selected by user?

html:

```
<div class="body-content text-center" ng-controller="QuizController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="q in questions">
            <h2>{{q.Id}}. {{q.Question}}</h2>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> {{q.isTrue}}
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> {{q.isFalse}}
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="prevQuestion()">Prev</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"ng-click="onSubmit()">Submit</button>

</div>
```

angularjs controller:

```
function controller($scope, quizService) {
        $scope.questions = [];

        updQuestion();

        function updQuestion() {
            var id = 1;

            quizService.getQuestions(id).success(function (data) {
                $scope.questions = data;
            });

            $scope.nextQuestion = function () {
                id++;
                quizService.getQuestions(id).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.questions = data;
                });
            };

            $scope.prevQuestion = function () {
                id--;
                quizService.getQuestions(id).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.questions = data;
                });
            };
        }
    }
```

And angular service:

```
function getQuestions(id) {
    return $http.get('/api/quiz/' + id);
}
```

Comment: you need to use shareable service, which will store the information of in answer & you could use them inside any of the component of your app & get the value of question's answer

Comment: Store all the questions which has been loaded into a $scope variable with the responses entered by the user. Every time on click of previous or next, check that the question is already loaded or not, if yes, instead of making a call to API, load it from the $scope with the response

Comment: @PrakashKalakoti, i think i've understand your idea, it would be very helpful if u could give me a little example how to use $scope from your suggestion.

Comment: @PankajParkar could you please give me a example of that, it would be very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Problem have been solved by adding array to angularjs like:

```
    $scope.binding = {
        answers: {}
    };
```

Then on this, i'm submiting my answer:

```
    $scope.setAnswer = function (answer, id) {
        $scope.binding.answers[id] = answer;
    };
```

After on html, in radio buttons need to add following:

```
ng-model="currentAnswer" ng-value="true" ng-click="setAnswer(true, q.Id)"
```